# BULK API V43 Pass Date/Time Value

Tags: rest-api, api, rest

I am trying to make a PUT call via fiddler passing in `Content-Type: text/csv`. I am able to pass in all fields, however it fails on one of the fields that requires a date/time value.

I am passing in the following date `2017-06-23 00:00:00Z`. I have tried passing it in single quotes(''), double quotes(""), `2017-06-23`, `2017-06-23 00:00:00`, but every single time I get the following error.

> INVALID_FIELD:Failed to deserialize field at col 10 Due to 2017-06-23 00:00:00Z "is not a valid value for the type xsd:dateTime".

How can I pass this date?

Comment: Hi John, welcome to SFSE. Please take a moment to scroll through the [tour] and read [ask]. The `[community]` tag is reserved for questions which relate to Salesforce Communities. Please read the descriptions for tags you apply and make sure they actually fit the question being asked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As specified [in the documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/datafiles_date_format.htm), you must use the following formats:

> yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.SSS+/-HHmm
>
> yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.SSSZ

Where yyyy is the four-digit year, MM is the two-digit month, dd is the two-digit day, HH is the two-digit zero-base 24 hour, mm is the two-digit minutes, ss is the two-digit seconds, and SSS is the three-digit milliseconds, Z indicates GMT (GMT+00:00), and +/-HHmm represents a time zone offset (e.g. +0700 or -0300).